# How to apply Sherman Morrison formula for rank 2 update?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

For obtaining the inverse update in BFGS, Sherman-Morrison needs to be applied twice since it is a rank 2 update. But what does it mean to apply it twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Woodbury-Sherman-Morrison formula, you can do it in one step:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

I hope this answers your problem :-).